# Pass variables between ansible roles

Tags: ansible

How to pass a variable defined in role1 to role2 in ansible?

I would like to know the best way to do this

```
---
- name: deploy VM
  hosts: localhost
  roles:
    - deploy_vm ## Here I want to deploy the VM and get the VM name/IP address in variable.
    - deploy_tomcat_on_above_vm   ## I would like to use the VM name and pass it over the second role.
```

I would like to use the VM name and pass it over the second role.

Answer (score 1):

Without any further details, the short answer is: just assign the var in your first role and use it in your second role.

Meanwhile, this is probably not the best way to handle what you are trying to do. I would:

1. Target `localhost` (as already done) to run the `deploy_vm` role.
2. From this point:

   - Either you have a [dynamic inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_dynamic_inventory.html) for your virtualization infrastructure and your new vm is already available (with possibly a group e.g. `tomcat_servers`)
   - Or you don't have a dynamic inventory and you need to [add that vm to the in-memory inventory yourself](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/add_host_module.html) in the same play.

     ```
     - name: Add my new created vm to in-memory inventory
       add_host:
         name: "{{ my_vm_fqdn_or_ip }}"
         groups:
           - tomcat_servers
         ansible_inventory_var_1: value1 #  Optional inventory vars...
         ansible_inventory_var_2: value2
     ```
3. You can now in a second play in the same playbook target your machine directly to deploy tomcat

   ```
   - name: Now I registered my new tomcat vm(s), go for install
     hosts: tomcat_servers

     roles:
       - role: deploy_tomcat
   ```

Comment: Thanks Zeitounator .....I used the add_host to define the in-memory and solved it.